# How to get variables from exception code block

Tags: java, exception

I want to get `user1.name` variable from `public static void FileRead()`to `private void jButton1ActionPerformed` but It doesn't read `user1.name`. Can you explain me how can I use that variable.

```
public static class Users {
    public String name;
    public String password;

    Users(String name1, String password1) {
        name = name1;
        password = password1;
    }

}

public static void FileRead() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/B_Ali/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication20/UserNamePassword.txt"));
        String[] s1 = new String[5];
        String[] s2 = new String[5];
        int i = 0;
        while ((s1[i] = in.readLine()) != null) {
            s1[i] = s2[i];
            i = i + 1;

            if (i == 1) {
                Users user1 = new Users(s2[0], s2[1]);
            }
            else if (i == 3) {
                Users user2 = new Users(s2[2], s2[3]);
            }
            else if (i == 5) {
                Users user3 = new Users(s2[4], s2[5]);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, user1.name);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

where should I declare it?
Edit: if i declare it as you said before. It becomes meaningless because i want to use `user1.name` which is defined in  `FileRead()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Declare it global.

`Users user1;`

```
public static class Users {
    public String name;
    public String password;

    Users(String name1, String password1) {
        name = name1;
        password = password1;
    }
    public String getName()
    { return this.name;
       }
    public String getPassword()
    {return this.password;
     }
}

Users user1, user2;
public static void FileRead() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/B_Ali/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication20/UserNamePassword.txt"));
        String[] s1 = new String[5];
        String[] s2 = new String[5];
        int i = 0;
        while ((s1[i] = in.readLine()) != null) {
            s1[i] = s2[i];
            i = i + 1;

            if (i == 1) {
                Users user1 = new Users(s2[0], s2[1]);
            }
            else if (i == 3) {
                Users user2 = new Users(s2[2], s2[3]);
            }
            else if (i == 5) {
                Users user3 = new Users(s2[4], s2[5]);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, user1.getName());
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Again you were declared User user1, user2 in your code

Comment: I forgot to seperate the code from the example decleration

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variables you need outside of the try clause like:

```
String global = null;

try{
    global = "abc";
    throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception e){
   if (global != null){
       //your code
   }
}
```